# Unix strace command

Tags: unix, strace

I found the following bash script in order to monitor cp progress.

```
#!/bin/sh
cp_p()
{
   strace -q -ewrite cp -- "${1}" "${2}" 2>&1 \
      | awk '{
        count += $NF
            if (count % 10 == 0) {
               percent = count / total_size * 100
               printf "%3d%% [", percent
               for (i=0;i<=percent;i++)
                  printf "="
               printf ">"
               for (i=percent;i<100;i++)
                  printf " "
               printf "]\r"
            }
         }
         END { print "" }' total_size=$(stat -c '%s' "${1}") count=0
}
```

I don't understand the "-ewrite" option for the strace command. The closest thing I've found is the man page for strace which is

> -e write=set Perform a full hexadecimal and ASCII dump of all the
>   data written to file descriptors
>   listed in the specified set. For
>   example, to see all output activity on
>   file descriptors 3 and 5 use -e
>   write=3,5. Note that this is
>   independent from the normal tracing of
>   the write(2) system call which is
>   controlled by the option -e
>   trace=write.

However I don't understand what the -ewrite option does.

Comment: Did you get the code from here @ http://chris-lamb.co.uk/2008/01/24/can-you-get-cp-to-give-a-progress-bar-like-wget/ and have you tried the alternative technique using secure copy **scp**? BTW You should have specified the source of the script in where you got it from...

Comment: Point of detail: `strace` is primarily Linux, though it may be available on some other platforms too.  Solaris uses `truss` or the Dtrace system, for instance; I can never remember what the equivalents on HP-UX and AIX are.

Comment: @tommieb75 yes I got the script from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

-ewrite means that only the "write" system call will be traced.

> -e expr     A qualifying expression which modifies which events
>                 to  trace  or how to trace them.  The format of the
>                 expression is:
>
> ```
>                      [qualifier=][!]value1[,value2]...
>
>           where qualifier is one of trace,  abbrev,  verbose,
>           raw,  signal,  read, or write and value is a quali-
>           fier-dependent symbol or number.  The default qual-
>           ifier  is trace.  Using an exclamation mark negates
>           the set of values.  For example, -eopen means  lit-
>           erally -e trace=open which in turn means trace only
>           the open system call.  By  contrast,  -etrace=!open
>           means  to  trace every system call except open.  In
>           addition, the special values all and none have  the
>           obvious meanings.
>
>           Note that some shells use the exclamation point for
>           history expansion even inside quoted arguments.  If
>           so,  you  must  escape the exclamation point with a
>           backslash.
> ```